# rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py

Tags: ros, rosrun, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
someone know if it's possible put this line `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0` inside  in a .launch file.

are "many" things to spawn or launch , and just for make it more practically  and eliminate some lines and terminals.
thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55232/rosrun-rosserial_python-serial_node.py/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what I have in my launch file:

```
  <node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" args="/dev/ttyACM0" name="serial_node" respawn="true"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) on 2014-01-31**:
I've had issues with this in the past, if launching the serial node right after rviz. It was causing rviz to crash immediately, but works fine when the two are launched separately. Not sure why